# delete-method binary search tree java. Setting leaf-node to null

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I don't understand why I can't set a leaf-node to null. It still exists in the tree.
Is it beacuse it's a local variable or that it's parent still has a reference to it? I'm deleting the root node, traversing down to the left-most node in the right sub-tree. The left-most node has no right-node. Please check the comment in the code.

```
    public void delete2(Integer value) {
    //getNode(value) is a helper-function. Returns the node to be changed 
        Node node = getNode(value);

        if(node != null) {
            if(node.hasLeft() && node.hasRight()) {

            Node pos = node;
            pos = node.right; //Right subtree

         while(pos.hasLeft()) //Traverse to the leftmost node
            pos = pos.left;

        node.value = pos.value; //Change value

        if(pos.hasRight()) 
            pos = pos.right;
        else {
        //I end up here. This doesn't work.
            pos = null;
        }
    } 
    else if (node.hasLeft() && !node.hasRight()) {
         //TODO
    }
    else if(!node.hasLeft() && node.hasRight()) {
         //TODO
    }
    else {
        //TODO
    }
}
else
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170999/java-binary-search-tree-delete-node-with-no-children?rq=1 The error is that the node still exists. But I found a solution here. Use a parent-reference to keep track. And then set parent-right or left to null.